# Failed to add wikinodes to ‘org-font-lock-extra-keywords

Tags: org-mode

I want to use org-wikinodes (http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-wikinodes.html)

Org wikinode is activated :

> (setq org-modules (quote (org-wikinodes)))

I can follow wikinodes links with C-c C-o.

However, the wikinodes links are not clickable. In addition, when I open an org file, I have the following message :

> "Failed to add wikinodes to ‘org-font-lock-extra-keywords’."

I saw in the org-list that this problem was resolved before (https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2015-06/msg00738.html)

Emacs version:

> GNU Emacs 25.2.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0, Carbon Version 157 AppKit 1404.47) of 2017-02-15
>
> Org mode version 9.0.5 (9.0.5-elpaplus @ /Users/sam/.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-20170210/)

Does anybody have the same issue?

Best,

Comment: This issue is now resolved under Org-Mode 9.0.7

Answer (score 0):

Find the line towards the end of `org-wikinodes.el` that reads:

```
(let ((m (member '(org-activate-plain-links (0 'org-link t))
```

and and change it to this:

```
(let ((m (member '(org-activate-plain-links (0 'org-link))
```

Then `M-x byte-recompile-directory` and `path-to/org-plus-contrib/`.

I honestly have no idea why this works... I just got lucky (perhaps someone else can chime in).

**A couple of things to note about this:**

If you ever update `org-wikinodes.el` your changes will be lost. Maybe there's a way to get this done in your `init.el` file instead?

I also notice that placing `(setq org-return-follows-link t)` in `init.el` has no effect links generated by `org-wikinodes`. No idea why...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. For the record, It now works with the last update of orgmode as you mention here https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33205/org-return-follows-link-with-org-wikinodes?noredirect=1&lq=1