# org-return-follows-link with org-wikinodes?

Tags: org-mode, org-link

I've noticed that placing `(setq org-return-follows-link t)` in your `init.el` has no effect on links created by `org-wikinodes.el`. When you hit  (or RET), it just cuts the link in half...

One point to clarify though, I made a slight modification in order to `org-wikinodes.el` to fix a bug that was preventing links from fontifying (see my answer to [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32278/failed-to-add-wikinodes-to-org-font-lock-extra-keywords)). So it's entirely possible that I missed something...

Ideas?

Comment: I don't use wikinodes, but it would *probably* be a similar solution as one of your previous questions -- i.e., add a new condition to `org-return` that looks for the face property of your link that is getting cut in half.  To see what properties are present, place your cursor on the link and type:  `C-u C-x =`  For example, one of your previous questions needed a new condition for the `org-footnote` face and if it was found, then we called `org-footnote-action`.  In summary, you *probably* need a new condition that looks for the face and calls whatever action you want if the condition is met.

Comment: Aha! I was hoping that @lawlist would join in! :D Okay, I placed the cursor on an `org-wikinodes` link and ran `C- C-x =`. These are the properties: face = org-link, fontified = t, help-echo = "Wiki Link", keymap = [Show], mouse-face = highlight.

Comment: `org-return` has built-in support for the `org-link` face that should trigger `org-open-at-point`.  You indicate that a `keymap` is present which could trump/supercede `org-return` if it has been set with a value for the return key.  Inasmuch as it should work out-out-of the box, your next step is to do a `M-x describe-key` on the Wiki Link and hit the return key and see if you are actually calling `org-return` which is the default behavior in `org-mode`.

Comment: Okay, `M-x describe key` [RET] with point on a wikinodes link yields: `RET (translated from <return>) runs the command org-return (found in
org-mode-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
‘org.el’...`

Comment: It sounds like everything should just work.  Try with `emacs -q` and just the `org-wikinodes.el` library with `(setq org-return-follows-link t)`

Comment: Okay, I created a fresh `init.el` file, only loading `org-wikinodes` and `(setq-org-return-follows-link t)`. Same issue... I'm running org 9.0.7 and wikinodes from Elpa, dated 2010-2017. Could there be a compatibility issue?

Comment: `org-return` has substantially changed between the stock version of `org-mode` 8.2.10 that ships with the latest stable release of Emacs and 9.0.7.  It looks like you have only three options with 9.0.7:  Customize `org-ts-regexp-both`, `org-tsr-regexp-both`, or `org-any-link-re`.  I'm not willing to upgrade to 9.0.7, but you may wish to read the doc-string for `org-any-link-re` and see if you can customize it to respect the wiki-links.  Alternatively, you can add a new condition similar to the old behavior and your previous question.

Comment: You would add a new condition to org-return?

Comment: I would read the doc-string for `org-any-link-re` and visit the source-code  with `M-x find-variable` and if I couldn't figure out how to modify it to match a wiki-link, then I'd modify the question seeking help with that aspect; or, I'd add a new condition like your previous question; or, I'd use the built-in stock version of `org-mode`; or ....  :)  You may wish to consider adding a specific example of what a wiki-link looks like just in case someone wants to take a stab at modifying the `org-any-link-re` to match that new condition (if it doesn't already exist).

Comment: hmm.. okay, so suppose I want to just stick with version 8.2.10. I don't think Emacs ships with the Contrib files. So how do I find the right version of `org-wikinodes.el` to work with 8.2.10? Thanks!

Comment: I was not able to find the answer with a preliminary Google search and I did not locate an old archive repository containing dates/versions, and the method they use for storing the source-code does not permit web browser view of the file history of commits, so I suppose it would be necessary to use certain tools after cloning the master to view the log history of commits for a certain file.  All of that is doable, but would require an investment of time.  I saw that the wiki-... jump sets `case-fold-search` to `nil` when jumping, but the 9.0.7 `org-return` condition for jumping does not ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have a solution. First, special thanks to Nicolas Goaziou for fixing a bug in `org-wikinodes` so that CamelCase links will now font-lock under Org-Mode 9.0.7. And a very special thanks to @lawlist for brainstorming this (endlessly) and showing me how to override `org-return`.

You'll need to update `org-mode` to get Nicolas' fix. Navigate to your `~/.emacs.d` directory and run

```
git clone git://orgmode.org/org-mode.git
cd org-mode
make autoloads
```

Then open your `init.el` file and add the code to activate `org-return-follows-link` and the `org-wikinodes` module:

```
(setq org-return-follows-link t)
(custom-set-variables
 '(org-modules (quote (org-wikinodes)))
 '(org-return-follows-link t))
```

Finally, add this code to override `org-return`:

```
;;; Override org-return
;;; Adds org-wikinode links to work with org-return-follows-link
(with-eval-after-load "org-wikinodes"
(defun org-return (&optional indent)
  "Goto next table row or insert a newline.

Calls `org-table-next-row' or `newline', depending on context.

When optional INDENT argument is non-nil, call
`newline-and-indent' instead of `newline'.

When `org-return-follows-link' is non-nil and point is on
a timestamp or a link, call `org-open-at-point'.  However, it
will not happen if point is in a table or on a \"dead\"
object (e.g., within a comment).  In these case, you need to use
`org-open-at-point' directly."
  (interactive)
  (let ((context (if org-return-follows-link (org-element-context)
                   (org-element-at-point))))
    (cond
     ;; In a table, call `org-table-next-row'.
     ((or (and (eq (org-element-type context) 'table)
               (>= (point) (org-element-property :contents-begin context))
               (< (point) (org-element-property :contents-end context)))
          (org-element-lineage context '(table-row table-cell) t))
      (org-table-justify-field-maybe)
      (call-interactively #'org-table-next-row))
     ;; On a link or a timestamp, call `org-open-at-point' if
     ;; `org-return-follows-link' allows it.  Tolerate fuzzy
     ;; locations, e.g., in a comment, as `org-open-at-point'.
     ((and org-return-follows-link
           (or (org-in-regexp org-ts-regexp-both nil t)
               (org-in-regexp org-tsr-regexp-both nil  t)
               (org-in-regexp org-any-link-re nil t)
               ;; Adam -- add org-wikinodes to list of regexp types
               (and (eq org-wikinodes-active t)
                    (org-in-regexp org-wikinodes-camel-regexp nil t)
                    (not (org-at-heading-p)))))
      (call-interactively #'org-open-at-point))
     ;; Insert newline in heading, but preserve tags.
     ((and (not (bolp))
           (save-excursion (beginning-of-line)
                           (let ((case-fold-search nil))
                             (looking-at org-complex-heading-regexp))))
      ;; At headline.  Split line.  However, if point is on keyword,
      ;; priority cookie or tags, do not break any of them: add
      ;; a newline after the headline instead.
      (let ((tags-column (and (match-beginning 5)
                              (save-excursion (goto-char (match-beginning 5))
                                              (current-column))))
            (string
             (when (and (match-end 4) (org-point-in-group (point) 4))
               (delete-and-extract-region (point) (match-end 4)))))
        ;; Adjust tag alignment.
        (cond
         ((not (and tags-column string)))
         (org-auto-align-tags (org-set-tags nil t))
         (t (org--align-tags-here tags-column))) ;preserve tags column
        (end-of-line)
        (org-show-entry)
        (if indent (newline-and-indent) (newline))
        (when string (save-excursion (insert (org-trim string))))))
     ;; In a list, make sure indenting keeps trailing text within.
     ((and indent
           (not (eolp))
           (org-element-lineage context '(item)))
      (let ((trailing-data
             (delete-and-extract-region (point) (line-end-position))))
        (newline-and-indent)
        (save-excursion (insert trailing-data))))
     (t (if indent (newline-and-indent) (newline)))))))
```